MS PowerAutomate - JSON output formatting issues
I've created a sample PowerAutomate workflow to trigger Github actions.

Trigger a HTTP action.
Initialize a sample json variable.
Create a Github issue action with the above json variable in the body.


Output: As shown in the image, json variable in the Github issue is ignoring spaces and newlines.
Expected: Json variable in the Github issue should retain the format.
I've very recently started using Power Automate. Any suggestions/help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
I've tried using the json() function in PowerAutomate but didn't make any difference.


I do have an idea but you may not like it. The advanced data operations connector has the ability to format the json indented sooooooo, it would need to be tested but it may work. You’d need to write some C# code to do it but it would be very few lines of code. Can you paste the json into your question? I might give it a crack.

@Skin any sample json should be ok. For example:
{
"fruit": "Apple",
"size": "Large",
"color": "Red"
}

I get that but it's always nice to work with the real thing.

What type of variable is it?  Text or object?  It would really help if you showed some screenshots.

When I paste the JSON into the string variable, the line breaks and spaces are being honoured (go to the code view on the step) so maybe it's something beyond that once it gets to GitHub.  Dunno ...!
